Extracting join information from stored procs in Postgres
I have a couple db which was migrated to Postgres sql. Generally have more than 1000+ procedures.
I need to grab all joins from procedures and function. Does someone know a solution?
I found Extracting join information from views/stored procs in SQL Server for Ms. Tried to change it to Postgres but didn't have a good result. Thanks

Look at pg_proc. The function/procedure source is in prosrc , but be sure and read the paragraph below the table for what that holds for different function/procedure languages.

Thanks for answer. I found it. Will try to parse
